# Circular container layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to do a circular container layout in Android? I'm trying to do a circular container for a WebView to show an effect like in the image:

[image]

In iOS I could do it by `UIViewController` layers:

```
CALayer *myLayer = self.layer;
[myLayer setCornerRadius:frame.size.width/2];
[myLayer setBorderWidth:LINE_THICKNESS];
[myLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

Is there something similar in Android to do it?

Comment: you may want to take a look at [this](https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/CircleLayout)

Comment: Thanks @cliffroot for your answer, but this draws a circle by Canvas but I want the container view layout to be a circle to put a WebView inside like in the image. I need to show and scroll the WebView inside a circle view layout.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:paddingLeft="1dip"
    android:paddingRight="1dip"
    android:background="@drawable/white_rounded_area"
    >
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/web_view"
            android:layout_width="300dip"
            android:layout_height="400dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Set padding according to your need to make webview round.

Comment: Thanks @AntiMatter for your answer, but I can't put paddings, the whole WebView should fit the circle layout container like in the image. This solution just put a rounded background drawable but if I should put paddings to not overlap the rounded corners with the webview.